# Somar mais um ID ao gerar mais um INPUT via javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu estou criando um sistema de votações, e antes de a pessoa gerar o input com as opções, a pessoa tem que escolher o número de opções que terá, depois ela vai pra um formulário com as alternativas de acordo com a quantidade que ela escolheu, porém eu quero por algo como Adicionar mais um campo, e eu consegui através do JAVASCRIPT.

Só que ele não está conseguindo fazer a contagem dos campos que vem através do javascript:

Através do javascript ele coloca mais um campo quando a pessoa clica no Botão, depois da div idDiv...

```
        
        echo'<form action="valida_enquete.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
            Título da sua enquete:<input type="text" name="titulo_enquete"><br>
            Descrição da enquete: <input type="text" name="descricao_enquete"><br><br>';
            
            if(isset($_GET['qtdade_opcoes'])){
                
                ?>
                <div id="idDiv">
                <?php
                for ($i=0; $i<$_GET['qtdade_opcoes']; $i++) { 
                    
                    $indice = $i+1;
                    echo'opção <input type="text" name="opcao[]"><br>';
                    echo'imagem <input type="text" name="img[]"><br>';
                

                echo' <input type="hidden" name="numero" value="'.$_GET['qtdade_opcoes'].'">';
                }
                echo '
                
                <input type="hidden" name="reality" value="'.$row['reality'].'">
                
                </div>';
            }
        
    ?>
```

Código javascript

```
window.onload = function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maximo = 5;   //maximo de 5 campos
   var i = 1;
   $('#add_div').click (function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();  //previne novos cliques
     if (i < maximo) {
       $('#idDiv').append('<div>\
          opção: <input type="text" name="opcao[]"/> <br> imagem:  <input type="text" name="img[]"/>\
          <a href="#" class="remove">Remover</a>\
           <?php    echo' <input type="hidden" name="numero" value="'.$_GET['qtdade_opcoes'].'">';
           ?></div>');
           i++;
     }
  });
 
    // Remove o div anterior
    $('#idDiv').on("click",".remove",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
      i--;
    });
});
};
```

Alguém me ajuda, por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é preciso declarar essa variável `i = 1` e depois ir incrementando, pode pegar esse valor sempre atualizado no click usando por exemplo esse seletor: `var i = $("#idDiv > div").length;` ou seja, os divs aninhados dentro de div com id "idDiv", e `length` para retornar a quantidade.

Simplificando, ficaria assim (inclui uns comentários):

```js
window.onload = function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maximo = 5;   //maximo de 5 campos
  
   $('#add_div').click (function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();  //previne novos cliques

      // total de divs aninhados abaixo de idDiv
      var i = $("#idDiv > div").length;

     // inverti esse if, para não ficar todo o código aninhado, e sair logo se puder adicionar nos itens
     if (i >= maximo) return;
     
     $('#idDiv').append('<div>\
opção: <input type="text" name="opcao[]"/> <br> imagem:  <input type="text" name="img[]"/>\
<a href="#" class="remove">Remover</a></div>');

  });
 
    // Remove o div anterior
    $('#idDiv').on("click",".remove",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent('div').remove();
    });
});
};
```

```css
#idDiv > div {
   padding: 5px;
   border: solid 1px #ddd;
   background-color: #eee
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idDiv">
  <div>
    opção: <input type="text" name="opcao[]"><br>
    imagem: <input type="text" name="img[]"><br>  
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add_div">Adicionar</button>
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso que a quantidade de inputs esteja dentro desse input, que some junto com o $_GET['qtdade_opcoes'] sempre que a pessoa for adicionar mais um input e assim por diante...  <input type="hidden" name="numero" value="'.$_GET['qtdade_opcoes'].'">

Comment: você pode por isso no código, eu removi pq não ia funcionar no exemplo, isso ai é PHP, mas não muda o fato que, se está adicionar/removento elementos com javascript, faz isso do lado cliente, e tanto faz usar aquela variável ou pegar sempre a quantidade de elementos usando um seletor

Comment: eu coloquei e ele não pega a quantidade de itens que o javascript adiciona, como faço pra pegar essa quantidade? essa é a dúvida

Comment: `var i = $("#idDiv > div").length;` essa variável tem a quantidade de "itens" (divs). No seu código, tem um input hidden com a quantidade de opições, basta pegar o valor desse input e subtrair a quantidade de itens que tem se eu entendi bem. Pode ser assim: `var totOpicoes =$('input[name ="numero"]').val()`

Comment: Juro que é a última vez, e como eu faço pra pegar no PHP uma tag do javascript?

Comment: pq esse valor tem q estar dentro do input pra eu somar

Comment: pode perguntar, se fizer `POST` da página, pode fazer assim: `$_REQUEST['numero']`. Agora se quiser o total de campos, sugiro criar outro campo hidden para guardar esse valor, por exemplo `<input t ype="hidden" name="totalItens" />`. Nesse caso, usa o mesmo comando, só usa o nome desse outro input. Agora no javascript é preciso ir atualizando ele cada vez que adicionar ou remover um item. Por exemplo, ao adicionar um item, depois de fazer o `append`, atualiza esse campo: `$('input[name ="totalItens"]').val(i+1)`, "i" é a variável que tem o total de itens, como adicinou mais um, basta somar 1

Comment: DEUUUUUUUU CERTO MTO OBRIGADO!

Comment: Ricardoooo, só mais uma coisa, quando tiver removendo o campo ele tem que tirar -1 de volta, eu coloquei     $('input[name ="totalItens"]').val(i-1) depois do remover, só que ta dando erro

Comment: Copiou o codigo `var i = $("#idDiv > div").length;` para dentro da function que faz delete? pode ser isso

Comment: Simmm muito obrigado, outra coisa, eu estou tentando mostrar o número da opção com o seguitne códgio ' + $("#idDiv > #AlternativaDiv").length'   porém ele ta mostrando do 0, como faço pra começar do 2?