# Identificar ID do input

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Galera, um help, acho que já não estou conseguindo itenficar onde estou errando.

Tem um form com 4 campos (item, descrição, unidade e quantidade) e um botão para ele ir adicionando mais linhas caso queira, utilizo o codigo abaixo para adicionar novas linhas;

```
$(".adicionarCampo").click(function () {
novoCampo = $("tr.linhas:first").clone();
novoCampo.find("input").val("");
novoCampo.insertAfter("tr.linhas:last");
removeCampo();
});
```

Este é o botão para ir adiconando mais linhas

```
<input type="button" name="Adicionar" id="Adicionar" class="adicionarCampo" value="+">
```

O usuario digita um item e o campo descrição e auto preenchido com o codigo abaixo.

```
function update(cod_atividade){
$.post("../../scripts/codigos_atividades.php", {cod_atividade:cod_atividade}, function(retorno){

dados = retorno.split("/");
 $('#descricao').val(dados[5]);
 });
}
```

Pegar o ID do input com nome descrição, deixo ele somente como leitura e o script acima coloca a informação da descrição conforme o item

```
<input name="descricao[]" type="text" required="required" class="descricao" id="descricao" size="40" maxlength="255" readonly="readonly" />
```

O problema é que se o usuario adicionar um novo campo(linha) e colocar um item, a descrição deste novo item muda somente no primeiro input, se ele adicionar 10 campos, ele fica mudando somente no primeiro input, e não naquele respectivo input.

Sei que o ID é unico e neste caso ele muda realmente a primeira linha, meu problema é que não sei como fazer o script que coloca a descrição identificar em qual id está agora sem afetar os que já foram feitos.

Já tentei fazendo o campo id com os colchete no fim mais não funciona.

```
<input name="descricao[]" type="text" required="required" class="descricao" id="descricao[]" size="40" maxlength="255" readonly="readonly" />
```

Gostaria de ums ideia de como fazer. Agradeço deste já.

EDIT:

Para vcs entenderem o que acontece.

Adicionei novas linhas e coloquei um item qualquer na primeira linhas. O Item G.10.05.005.095 é Máquina fotográfica

Depois cliquei em adicionar novas linhas (em amarelo) e inserir um outro item qualquer F.30.70.005.010 é Máquina de Chave. Ao inves do item debaixo acrescentar a descrição na linha dele, ele muda a linha de cima.

[image: Adicionando o item G.10.05.005.095 na primeira linha]

[image: Adicionando o item F.30.70.005.010 e ele muda também a primeir linha, ao inves de mudar na dele]

Comment: mas precisa mesmo do ID? ele tem de ser única e seria um trabalho ficar controlando isso e atribuindo IDs, acho que pode usar nomente o `name` e ler esse valor. Esse é um cenário bem comum, de adicionar itens manualmente, veja essa pergunta, tem um exemplo e não usa ID: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/492776/somar-mais-um-id-ao-gerar-mais-um-input-via-javascript  Se quiser mais ajuda, coloque toda a parte funcional do código e monte um exemplo demonstrando o problema

Comment: e se você criar uma variável contendo números cujo valor inicial seja 0, e quando criar o novo input ele coloca o id do input alguma coisa + o valor dessa variável e incrementar em 1 o valor da variável, será que não resolveria? Não entendi muito bem seu problema.

Comment: Olá Ricardo e Isaque, obrigado por interagir, não precisar ser necessariamente o ID, pode ser pelo nome ou class, por exemplo. Editei a pergunta para vcs entenderem o que acontece.

Comment: @FidelesSanches, sem ver o html fica difícil ajudar, mas está usando um `clone`, se fizer um clone de um elemento que tem um ID isso vai te gerar um problema pq o ID deve ser único, e se tiver alguma referência a ele, não importa quantas linhas insira, vai referenciar o primeiro elemento. Já que vai fazer `clone()`, remova os IDs, isso vai editar problemas. `id="descricao[]"` isso não funciona como já notou, por isso remova os ids